# unwanted multiple template class instantiate throug multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, templates

I am havin `SystemType` class template, which should give unique id for every system.

```
//.h file:
extern atomic_counter MY_API s_nextSystemTypeId;

template <typename T>
class SystemType 
{
public:
    static unsigned getId();

private:
    static unsigned next();
};


template <typename T>
unsigned SystemType<T>::getId()
{
    static unsigned sysId = SystemType<T>::next();
    return sysId;
}

template <typename T>
unsigned SystemType<T>::next()
{
    return s_nextSystemTypeId++;
}
```

.

```
//.cpp file

atomic_counter s_nextSystemTypeId(0);
```

But this code does not work when it is used through multiple DLLs. 
In one dll:

```
SystemType<System1>::getId(); // = 0
SystemType<System2>::getId(); // = 1
SystemType<System1>::getId(); // = 0
```

but when using in other dll

```
SystemType<System1>::getId(); // = 2
SystemType<System2>::getId(); // = 3
SystemType<System1>::getId(); // = 2
```

How can I enforce only one template class instantiated?